# Beginner looking for help for printing in python

Tags: python

`print ("ln(x) at " ,x "is: " ,lnx)`

I keep getting syntax error on the last quotation mark in there.

No matter what kind of print statements I do, it seems it does not let me put multiple quotation marks in the same print. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
print ("ln(x) at ", x, "is: ", lnx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are much better of shifting into the new print format style:

```
print('ln(x) at {} is: {}'.format(x, lnx))
```

Using this form gives you access to the [Format Specification Mini-Language](//docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatspec), which allows you specify widths, number of decimals to print, and much more.

Most likely the following would look better where I print the logarithm with 4 decimals:

```
print('ln({}) = {:,.4f}'.format(x, lnx)
```

Note that if you want to include the quotation marks, you either need to escape it or switch the outer quotation to the other set. Say you want to print *Billy "Bobby" Thornton* these two ways could do that:

```
print('Billy "Bobby" Thornton')
print("Billy \"Bobby\" Thornthon")
```

Comment: You have much better control, and you kind of separate how it is supposed to look, and the actual values you are printing. And it's the suggested version for printing since Python 2.6, if I'm not mistaken